# popularTags is undefined in PopularTagsComponent

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, ngrx

I am implementing the realworld.io project in Angular. I have a global-feed.component component. In this component, I want to show the popularTags.component component. The component should display a list of popular tags.

[image]

To do this, I created a smart popularTags.component component. It contains a store and an interface. In redux, I see that I get Action popularTags and object tags. But this object is not binding in popularTags.component. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

popularTags.component.ts:

```
export class PopularTagsComponent implements OnInit {
  popularTags$!: Observable<PopularTagType[] | null >
  isLoading$!: Observable<boolean>
  error$!: Observable<string | null>

  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeValues()
    this.fetchData()
    this.popularTags$.subscribe(tags => console.log(tags, 'popularTags'));
  }

  initializeValues(): void {
    this.popularTags$ = this.store.pipe(select(popularTagsSelector))
    this.isLoading$ = this.store.pipe(select(isLoadingSelector))
    this.error$ = this.store.pipe(select(errorSelector))
  }

  fetchData(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(getPopularTagsAction())
  }
}
```

popularTags.component.html:

```
<app-loading *ngIf="isLoading$ | async"></app-loading>
<app-error-message
  *ngIf="error$ | async"
  [message]="error$ | async"
></app-error-message>
<!-- *ngIf="popularTags$ | async" -->
<div class="sidebar" >
  <p>Popular Tags</p>
  <div class="tag-list">
    <a
      *ngFor="let popularTag of popularTags$ | async"
      [routerLink]="['/tags', popularTag]"
      class="tag-default tag-pill"
    >
      {{ popularTag }}
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

popularTags.service.ts:

```
import {PopularTagType} from 'src/app/shared/types/popularTag.type'
import {environment} from 'src/environments/environment'
import { GetPopularTagsResponseInterface } from '../types/getPopularTagsResponse.interface'

@Injectable()
export class PopularTagsService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPopularTags(): Observable<PopularTagType[]> {
    const url = environment.apiUrl + '/tags';
    return this.http.get<GetPopularTagsResponseInterface>(url).pipe(
      map((response: GetPopularTagsResponseInterface) => {
        return response.tags;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

selector.ts:

```
import {PopularTagsStateInterface} from '../types/popularTagsState.interface'

export const popularTagsFeatureSelector = createFeatureSelector<PopularTagsStateInterface>('popularTags')

export const popularTagsSelector = createSelector(
  popularTagsFeatureSelector,
  (popularTagsState: PopularTagsStateInterface) => popularTagsState.data
)

export const isLoadingSelector = createSelector(
  popularTagsFeatureSelector,
  (popularTagsState: PopularTagsStateInterface) => popularTagsState.isLoading
)

export const errorSelector = createSelector(
  popularTagsFeatureSelector,
  (popularTagsState: PopularTagsStateInterface) => popularTagsState.error
)
```

Comment: Can you provide selectors' code? Looks like they are causing the issue.  To test it, try to replace `this.popularTags$ = this.store.pipe(select(popularTagsSelector))` with `this.popularTags$ = of(['a', 'b', 'c']);` (of from rxjs). If it works, then your selector is corrupted.

Comment: Yes. I edited the post and added a selector

Comment: I checked your code and it works.

Comment: and what could be wrong with the selector?

Comment: Now one I look at it, even your reducer can be corrupted. Check if your reducer is saving data correctly. Use dev tools, but don't just check the action, but the actual state. You can also provide some code of it